# How to get a return value from a background server thread

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

So I am creating a simple application that implements a Vector Clock algorithm.  The application does three things.
1. It can do an internal event (in my case, I chose this to be some simple algebra)
2. Send a message (across a Socket connection)
3. Receive a message (via ServerSocket)

After any of these event occur, you must update your own local vector clock.  But when you receive a message, the sender's clock is appended to the end of the message and you must now do some update() on you own local clock based on what clock was received.

The way I went about this was to first start a server thread that accepts incoming connections.  Each incoming connection then creates its own thread within the server thread.  My code for this is:

```
new Thread() {                              //This thread is the server handler that will accept new clients for communication
        public void run(){
            try{
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);   //Created a new server for clients (other users) to connect to              
                while (true) {
                    ConnectionWorker cw = new ConnectionWorker(server.accept());    //Accept the new client
                    Thread t = new Thread(cw);                                      //Start the client thread
                    t.start();                                                      //Start the thread
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        {
            start();
        }
    };
```

So now, my ConnectionWorker class will receive a message that includes the vector clock.  My questions becomes, what would be the best way to get this message back into my main thread (i.e. the one that handles internal events and send events)?  My main thread is where I have my vector clock and do all of my operations on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your execution path, but check out `BlockingQueue`, `ScheduledExecutorService`, and `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

> My questions becomes, what would be the best way to get this message back into my main thread

You might consider switching to use an `ExecutorService`.  Then you can submit a `Callable` which with which you can easily return the result to the main thread.

```
// this is for 1 thread but you can also use a fixed number of threads or dynamic
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<SomeResult> future = threadPool.submit(new Callable<SomeResult>() {
    public SomeResult call() {
       // thread code goes here
    }
});
// after you submit the last job, you can shutdown the pool
threadPool.shutdown();
...
// later you can get the result
SomeResult result = future.get();
```